# Warning and fatal error when using git on windows?

Tags: windows, git, access-denied

When I want to get the current status or use any git command I will see these two lines of errors:

```
warning: unable to access 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git': Permissio
fatal: cannot use C:/Program Files (x86)/Git as an exclude file
```

Where is the problem ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance that `git config --global core.excludesfile` is showing the file mentioned?

Comment: @iltempo it shows : C:/Program Files (x86)/Git

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Use an exclude file that exists

As indicated by @iltempo's comment - this error occurs because there is a reference to read the file `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git` which isn't a file or doesn't exist.

A [global git ignore file](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) is a good idea - after creating one (if you don't already have one) - update the location that git is using so that it's used:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile C:/Users/me/global.gitignore
```

Alternatively to just remove the error, remove the reference:

```
git config --global --unset core.excludesfile
```