# just installed git but when I try to git status gives me a fatal error

Tags: git

I'm really new on Git, just installed and when I do `git status` it gives me this error:

```
fatal: cannot use /Users/.gitignore as an exclude file
```

After reading the question linked in the comments, I also tried this:

```
Pro-de-HackNew:~ hacknew$ git config --global core.excludesfile
/usr/local/bin/git/global.gitignore
Pro-de-HackNew:~ hacknew$ git config --global --unset core.excludesfile
Pro-de-HackNew:~ hacknew$ git status
fatal: cannot use /Users/hacknew/.gitignore as an exclude file
Pro-de-HackNew:~ hacknew$
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: it seens you're trying to exclude a file that cannot be excluded.

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298642/4386427

Comment: tried but not sure if I am doing it wrong

Comment: If /Users/.gitignore does not exist, create it. It can be empty.

Comment: how can I know if exist or not?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the information from your existing comments into your question.

Comment: thanks for your help Scott