# How to un-ignore a folder after global ignore?

Tags: bash, git, gitignore

In git bash I ignored the node_modules folder, with this command:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

then use command `git status` and `git add .` both not work

and get this message:

```
warning: unable to access 'node_modules': Permission denied
fatal: cannot use node_modules as an exclude file
```

Is there any way to un-ignore the ignored folder? What I tried:

1. Remove the current node_modules folder, and create and new one and paste in same content. Then `git status` still gets the same message.
2. Command `rm -rf .git` then re-create git repo `git init` still get the fatal message.
3. Command `rm -rf .gitignore`. still get the fatal message.

===
update

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298642/7090538) that removes the error message.

And for people who are new to it like me, an article explaining how to use gitignore [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: The global config is in `~/.gitconfig` (or `~/.config/git/config`), if you want to remove the directive..

Comment: What exactly did you *put into* the file `~/.gitignore`?

Comment: @torek a myprojects/node_modules folder. But after ignoring it, the other git command always give the error message.